# Ruby on Rails won't render edit page without id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason the edit action won't render i get this error and is using show action instead of edit but the same form works for the render :new action

- do not focus on the params[:preview], i am talking about the last `render :edit`

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Admin::Blog::Posts#update
  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/blog/posts", :id=>""} missing required keys: [:id]`

```
def edit
    @post = Post.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
  end

def update
    @post = Post.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    if params[:publish]
      @post.publish
    elsif params[:draft]
      @post.draft
    end

    if params[:preview]
      if @post.published?
        @post.draft
      end

      if @post.update(blog_post_params)
        flash[:success] = "some text "

        redirect_to blog_post_url(@post)
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
    if @post.update(blog_post_params)
      flash[:success] = "Post was successfully updated."
      redirect_to edit_admin_blog_post_url(@post)
    else
      render :edit
    end

  end
```

form

```
<%= form_for [:admin,:blog, @post] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="field panel">
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div class="field panel">
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions panel text-right">
      <% if @post.published? %>
        <%= f.submit "Save Changes",name: "publish", class: "tiny button radius success" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= f.submit "Publish",name: "publish", class: "tiny button radius success" %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit 'Mark as Draft', name: "draft", class: "tiny button radius " %>
      <% if @post.created_at %>
        <%= f.submit 'Preview', name: "preview", class: "tiny button radius warning" %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to 'Back', admin_blog_posts_path, class: "tiny button radius secondary" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field panel">
      <%= f.label :body %><br>
      <%= f.cktext_area :body, :height => '800px', :id => 'sometext' %>
    </div>




  </div>

<% end %>
```

relevant routes

```
namespace :admin do
     namespace :blog do
          get '', to: 'welcome#index', as: '/'
          resources :posts
     end
end
```

post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  has_many :comments
  before_validation :generate_permalink
  validates :permalink, uniqueness: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true


  def generate_permalink
    self.permalink = title.parameterize
  end

  def to_param
    permalink
  end

end
```

Comment: How are you getting to the edit action?  What is the link you clicked on?

Comment: added form. Clicked the save changes button @japed

Comment: Can you post the relevant contents of your config/routes.rb file?

Comment: shoudn't it be `redirect_to admin_blog_post_url(@post)`?

Comment: @Undo i added my routes thanks

Comment: @YuryLebedev i am deliberately trying to show error messages due to validations but it should be render not redirect else it won't retain the error messages.

Comment: It's very bad to render HTML in non-get actions, because when the user refreshes the page, that non-get request is sent again. Usually **redirect** is good.

Comment: Aetherus its not working.You have to use render and the action not redirect if you want to retain the error messages. With redirect you have to again specify @post value before redirect and because that is a new instantiation it does not retain error message. it works with render it just does not work in this case only. You only use redirect when you have nested routes. i have not nested routes in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i know why you get this error.

In the `edit` action you use `Post.find_by_permalink(params[:id])` to find your post, which returns `nil` if nothing was found. And since you may change the `title` attribute, your permalink is updated (i guess), and your post is not found. The controller still renders the action, with `nil` `@post`, and cannot generate the url for the form.

Try using `Post.find_by_permalink!(params[:id])` instead, and you will get a 404.

I would actually suggest you to use regular `find` in the admin area, since the permalink might change.

Comment: you are right. That is the root of the cause, thank you! BUT i am using the same model for everything, is there a workaround this?

Comment: You could try moving the callback, which sets the permalink, after the validation, so it would change the permalink only if the changes to the model are valid.

Comment: i can't see how that would work on my case as the problem is with the way i use permalinks, there is this function to_param thats automatically called from the model. I added my model above for reference.

Comment: I'm not talking about `to_param`, i'm saying you should change this: `before_validation :generate_permalink` to this: `after_validation :generate_permalink`. But of course then you need to validate the uniqueness of your title instead.

Comment: Then you can just generate the url, avoiding the `to_param` method like this: `admin_post_url(@post.id)`, and using regular `find` method

Comment: where should i input `admin_post_url(@post.id)` ?

Comment: In your case it should be in the form tag `<%= form_for admin_post_path(@post.id) do |f| %>`.